# lxc-create runs without errors, the zfs filesystem is created, but the container is not created

Tags: 16.04, lxc, zfs

I'm trying lxc for the first time, by following https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html and the man pages.

The `lxc-create` command runs without errors, and creates the zfs `/lxc/u1` filesystem, mounted on `/lxc/u1/rootfs`.

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ # lxc-create -t download --bdev zfs --lxcpath=/lxc -n u1 -- --dist ubuntu --release xenial --arch amd64 
Setting up the GPG keyring
Downloading the image index
Downloading the rootfs
Downloading the metadata
The image cache is now ready
Unpacking the rootfs

---
You just created an Ubuntu container (release=xenial, arch=amd64, variant=default)

To enable sshd, run: apt-get install openssh-server

For security reason, container images ship without user accounts
and without a root password.

Use lxc-attach or chroot directly into the rootfs to set a root password
or create user accounts.
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ # lxc-ls --fancy
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ # zfs list
NAME     USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
lxc      390M  1.27T    20K  /lxc
lxc/u1   389M  1.27T   389M  /lxc/u1/rootfs
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ #
```

Why does `lxc-ls` not show `u1`?

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to add --lxcpath=/lxc to *every* lxc command :(

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ # sudo lxc-ls --lxcpath=/lxc --fancy
NAME STATE   AUTOSTART GROUPS IPV4 IPV6 
u1   STOPPED 0         -      -    -
```

I fixed this with:

```
echo "lxc.lxcpath = /lxc" > /etc/lxc/lxc.conf
```